# Adding multiple rows in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written following to add 200 rows to table

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE PROCEDURE proc()
BEGIN
SET @i=0;
SET @qty=200;

INSERT INTO leads (`id`, `owner_id`, `is_published`) VALUES;

for($i=0;$i< $qty;$i++){
  ('', '1', '1', '2020-11-22 16:53:42');
   }

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Query runs successfully in sqlworkbench, No record is added tho in the table.
Does anyone see any thing fishy there ?
Ps: This is my first day in mysql and spent like 3 hours to write this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is a recursive CTE:

```
insert into (`id`, `owner_id`, `is_published`) 
    with recursive n as (
          select 1 as n
          union all
          select n + 1
          from n
          where n < 200
         )
    select  . . . -- whatever you want to insert here '', '1', '1', '2020-11-22 16:53:42'
    from n;
```

No looping is necessary.

Comment: ok, you query didnt work, It ran successfully but nothing was added to the table

Comment: Excess `, '1'` fragment. `NULL` instead of `''` (`id` must be autoincrement).

Comment: @Sara . . . You need to set up the `insert` logic so it works.  I just copied what is in your question but there are three columns in the `insert` and four values in the `select`.  You need to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Your should add your insert statement after for loop:

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE PROCEDURE proc()
BEGIN
SET @i=0;
SET @qty=200;


for($i=0;$i<= $qty;$i++){
INSERT INTO leads (`id`, `owner_id`, `is_published`) 
VALUES ('', '1', '1', '2020-11-22 16:53:42');
   }

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: for some reason it was giving error when I was using for loop so I used WHILE and tht worked

Answer (score 0):

ok This is how I solved my problem
Created a stored procedure from left menu Selected  **Schemas** and from there selected **Stored procedure** and added following

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;

    WHILE counter <= 997 DO
        INSERT INTO `DBName`.`tableName` (`id`, `owner_id`, `is_published`) VALUES ('', '1', '2020-11-22 16:53:42');
        SET counter = counter + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

Thankyou everyone for your prompt reply.

BR
Saraa[image]